# В каком месте кода ошибка?

Tags: javascript, html

Задача заключается в том, чтобы взять значение из input и добавить его в div

```
function get() {
    var prod = document.querySelector("prod inp").value;
    var out = document.querySelector("out").innerHTML = prod;
}
```

(вызов функции по клику добавлен в  в html*)

Comment: И где же ошибка?

Comment: Тот же вопрос. Но код не работает

Comment: Приведите html и код вызова функции get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `"prod inp"` → `".prod .inp"` или `"#prod .inp"`
2. `"out"` → `".out"`
3. `innerHTML` → `textContent`
4. `var out =` просто лишнее

```
function get() {
    var prod = document.querySelector("#prod .inp").value;
    document.querySelector(".out").textContent = prod;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Очень глупая была ошибка, исправлю.